# Android Maps V2: how to remove north indicator

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new to maps v2... I would like to know how to remove the north indicator from the view of the google map.

This one:
[image]

Comment: hi, i want to add this direction indicator in map. How to add it? Pls help me.

Comment: Hi! For me, using the maps v2 for android, it showed automatically. But I think that if you don't see it you should use: mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false). With mMap being a GoogleMap object. If you are using v1 maps I don't know how to help you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn it off using the

```
UiSettings.setCompassEnabled(false);
```

Take a look at the API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings